# ¿Cómo evaluar una condición en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server, que a su vez tiene un cursor y todo va bien.

El asunto es que tengo que evaluar si se repiten caracteres en el campo `Nombre` de la base de datos. Lo hago acá:

```
select (len(Nombre) - DATALENGTH(replace(Nombre, 'a', ''))) / len('a')
from dbo.Usuariostest 
where Nombre = @USUARIOS
```

lo que pasa, y lo que necesito, es ver cómo puedo hacer una condición para que si ese nombre tiene dos caracteres iguales, cambie el estado de otro campo de tipo bool a **falso**.

Adjunto completo lo que tengo

```
USE [mbctest]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[VERUSUARIOS]    Script Date: 28/12/2016 23:56:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VERUSUARIOS]
    AS

    BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @USUARIOS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @var INT

    DECLARE  CURSORUSUARIOSS CURSOR 

    FOR SELECT USUARIO FROM DBO.USUARIOSTEST

    OPEN CURSORUSUARIOSS;

    FETCH CURSORUSUARIOSS INTO @USUARIOS

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)

    BEGIN

    SET @var = (select (len(Nombre) - DATALENGTH(replace(Nombre, 'a', ''))) / len('a')
    from dbo.Usuariostest where Nombre = @USUARIOS)


    UPDATE DBO.USUARIOSTEST SET HABILITADO=0 where @varn = 2


    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSORUSUARIOSS INTO @USUARIOS

    END

    CLOSE CURSORUSUARIOSS

    DEALLOCATE CURSORUSUARIOSS

    END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
       SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERRNUMBER
       , ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ERRSEVERITY
       , ERROR_STATE() AS ERRSTATE
       , ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ERRPROCEDURE
       , ERROR_LINE() AS ERRLINE
       , ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRMESSAGE

END CATCH
```

Comment: No incluyas imágenes con el texo del procedimiento. Elimina la imagen y pega el texto directamente. Eso facilita que podamos ayudarte haciendo referencia a parte de tu código.

Comment: ¿Por qué usás un cursor?

Comment: Los dos caracteres son siempre una 'a'?

Comment: Lo uso porque así se me pide en el problema que tengo que resolver @pa

Comment: @mcNets lo que hace es verificar cuantas letras "a" tiene el registro del campo **Nombre**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo deseas realizar de manera necesaria con un `CURSOR` lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma. Vas a necesitar un campo `Id`, yo utilicé uno que se llama `UserId` (este será necesario para realizar el `UPDATE` posteriormente). Las modificaciones a tu *procedure* son las siguientes:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VERUSUARIOS]
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @USUARIOS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @var INT
    DECLARE @UsuarioId INT
    DECLARE @i INT
    DECLARE @char CHAR

    SET @i = 0
    SET @char = ''

    DECLARE CURSORUSUARIOSS CURSOR LOCAL
    FOR
    ---
    SELECT UserId, Nombres
    FROM dbo.Usuariostest

    OPEN CURSORUSUARIOSS;
    FETCH CURSORUSUARIOSS INTO @UsuarioId, @USUARIOS
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        PRINT @USUARIOS
        PRINT LEN(@USUARIOS)

        BEGIN
            WHILE @i < LEN(@USUARIOS)
            BEGIN
                SELECT @i = @i + 1
                SET @char = SUBSTRING(@USUARIOS, @i, 1)

                UPDATE dbo.Usuariostest
                SET HABILITADO = 0
                WHERE UserId = @UsuarioId AND LEN(Nombres) - LEN(REPLACE(Nombres, @char, '')) > 1 --Esta línea hace la magia, si el caracter se encuenta más de una vez es cuando se cumple la condición
            END
        END
        SET @i = 0
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM CURSORUSUARIOSS
        INTO @UsuarioId, @USUARIOS

    END
    CLOSE CURSORUSUARIOSS
    DEALLOCATE CURSORUSUARIOSS
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERRNUMBER
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ERRSEVERITY
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ERRSTATE
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ERRPROCEDURE
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ERRLINE
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRMESSAGE
END CATCH
```

**Nota:** Adecué tu código a una tabla de usuarios que utilizo, si llegaras a tener algún error solo adecúa los nombres de los campos y/o tablas.

**UPDATE**: Se quita un `CURSOR` que no era necesario

Comment: Me sirvio perfecto los cambios que realizaste **Flxtr ** pura vida.

Comment: @Kevin a la orden bro :)